# NSLog(...) improper format specifier affects other variables?

Tags: objective-c, formatting, stack, printf, nslog

I recently wasted about half an hour tracking down this odd behavior in NSLog(...):

```
NSString *text = @"abc";
long long num = 123;
NSLog(@"num=%lld, text=%@",num,text); //(A)
NSLog(@"num=%d, text=%@",num,text); //(B)
```

Line (A) prints the expected "num=123, text=abc", but line (B) prints "num=123, text=**(null)**".

Obviously, printing a `long long` with `%d` is a mistake, but can someone explain why it would cause `text` to be printed as null?

Comment: If you compile with the -Wall option, the compiler will warn you about problems like this; I also strongly recommend the -Werror so warnings always break the build.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield, just a note that support for format checking, ala `-Wformat`, has always been a bit dodgy in gcc/objc.  This seems to be getting better with later versions of the compiler, but I just did a quick check under Xcode 3.1 and it did not catch the above error.

Comment: It doesn't catch the error because -Wformat only works on C-strings (like in printf) and is completely unable to parse NSString* object constants (which NSLog uses).

Comment: @Jason Coco, Err, no, there's been partial support for doing `-Wformat` checking in `gcc` for awhile, it's just been wonky.  Note the prototype for `NSLog` from the headers: `void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, 1, 2)));`

Comment: @johne, Err, no, they've had this NSString specifier since leopard but it's more than wonky, it's silently ignored.

Comment: @Jason Coco, For the prepackaged compilers that ship with release versions of Xcode, you might be right- because of the wonkiness, they punted and just silently swallow it up.  But grab a copy of the compiler source and have a look-see. It's in there, and if you're clever, you can even get it to acknowledge that it does more than just 'ignore' it.  I can't remember why it was wonky in the first place any more.  The summary is this, though: you'll most likely see `printf` like format checking for `(CF|NS)String` strings in the future, possibly 10.6.  A big chunk of it is already there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just messed up memory alignment on your stack. I assume than you use newest Apple product with x86 processor. Taking these assumptions into account your stack looks like that in both situations:

```
   |      stack          | first | second |
   +---------------------+-------+--------+
   |        123          |       |  %d    |
   +---------------------+ %lld  +--------+
   |         0           |       |  %@    |
   +---------------------+-------+--------+
   |   pointer to text   | %@    |ignored |
   +---------------------+-------+--------+
```

In first situation you put on stack 8 bytes and then 4 bytes. And than NSLog is instructed to take back from stack 12 bytes (8 bytes for `%lld` and 4 bytes for `%@`).

In second situation you instruct NSLog to first take 4 bytes (`%d`). Since your variable is 8 bytes long  and holds really small number its upper 4 bytes will be 0. Then when NSLog will try to print text it will take `nil` from stack.

Since sending message to `nil` is valid in Obj-C NSLog will just send `description:` to `nil` get probably nothing and then print (null).

In the end since Objective-C is just C with additions, caller cleans up whole this mess.

Answer (score 1):

How varargs are implemented is system-dependent. But what is likely happening is that the arguments are stored consecutivelyly in a buffer, even though the arguments may be different sizes. So the first 8 bytes (assuming that's the size of a `long long int`) of the arguments is the `long long int`, and the next 4 bytes (assuming that's the size of a pointer on your system) is the `NSString` pointer.

Then when you tell the function that it expects an `int` and then a pointer, it expect the first 4 bytes to be the `int` (assuming that's the size of an `int`) and the next 4 bytes to be the pointer. Because of the particular endianness and arrangement of arguments on your system, the first 4 bytes of the `long long int` happens to be the least significant bytes of your number, so it prints 123. Then for the object pointer, it reads the next 4 bytes, which in this case is the most significant bytes of your number, which is all 0, so that gets interpreted as a `nil` pointer. The actual pointer never gets read.